# What is meant by the "'sons' of Israel"

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

I've noticed that in [Deuteronomy 31:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.31.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and also [Numbers 15:38](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.15.38?lang=bi&aliyot=0) that only the 'sons' were included. Were these things not required for women?

Comment: In Hebrew (and many other languages) mixed gender groups are referred to in the masculine. English plural pronouns are all, it so happens, epicene.

Comment: Why was 'sons and daughters' used in Deuteronomy 32:19?

Comment: Good question .

Comment: On the surface, Deuteronomy 32:19 uses more poetic "sons and daughters" because it is part of "The Song of Haazinu." However, the following [commentaries](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.32.19?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) explain the particular reason for using this unusual language: Ibn Ezra, Ramban, Sforno, Rabbeinu Bahya, Haamek Davar, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is borne out of using an inaccurate translation. Hebrew word בני could be translated as either "sons", "children", or even "people of." This is a common translation error. Literal translation of Hebrew into English is impossible, and translation of individual words very often must be guided by the context.

Some examples of better translations of Deuteronomy 31:19:

The Koren Jerusalem Bible: "*children of Israel*"

1985 JPS Translation: "*people of Israel*"

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. Is "sons" necessarily male progeny in English? Like "Daughters of the Revolution" aren't literally children

Comment: So in this context woman can wear tzitzit? And what of Deuteronomy 16:16 implying that only men should take part?

Comment: @Pabble women may still be exempt from tzitzit for a different reason (that's debated in the Talmud)

Comment: @Double AA - any examples of "sons" referring to both sexes in English?